# Action to take when android app is upgraded

Tags: android

I am planning to update my android app . Is there any callback or action that is triggered when an app is updated . I just want to show a toast message when user first launch the app after upgrade.

Comment: You can match your version code or name when app updated. Also you can use In app update functionality. for more info check this https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates

Comment: @Nik thanks , but I am not using app bundle , it seems it is an app bundle specific feature,

Comment: You can save your app version code or version name in preference and match that value with your Launcher activity and if you found different then show your toast.. and update your version code or version name to preference.

Comment: save last version that was launched into shred prefs, check it at startup, if id does not match current - then it is the first launch after update.

Comment: you can also check the build number against the last release. However, any approach you do of comparing number of versions or codes means you'll always have to keep track of this in future releases